# How to copy a folder with specific name from a location with other folders

Tags: file, batch-file, directory

I am trying to do a copy of a folder from a location with other folders. How can I do this?

Here is what I have so far:
So I am finding a folder which starts with `New Project *` and renaming it `Report_current date`. Now I need to copy just this folder to C:\Complete.

```
@echo off

move "C:\ECU\ECU1\New Project*" "C:\ECU\ECU1\Report_%Date:~-10,2%_%Date:~-7,2%_%Date:~-4,4%"

pause
```

Comment: You mention copying the folder but you are using the `move` command. Please confirm which of the two you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply specify that you want to move the folder to C:\Complete as you rename it

move "C:\ECU\ECU1\New Project*" "C:\Complete\Report_%Date:~-10,2%%Date:~-7,2%%Date:~-4,4%"

Answer (score 0):

```
xcopy "C:\ECU\ECU1\Report_%Date:~-10,2%%Date:~-7,2%%Date:~-4,4%\*" "C:\Complete\"
```

should do your copy. Perhaps

```
xcopy "C:\ECU\ECU1\Report_%Date:~-10,2%%Date:~-7,2%%Date:~-4,4%\*" "C:\Complete\Report_%Date:~-10,2%%Date:~-7,2%%Date:~-4,4%\"
```

would be better - creating a new subdirectory with the date, which should obviate the need to caution against the next obvious point : what do you want to do when you have duplicate filenames?

And perhaps you's want to add some switches to the `xcopy` command - like `/s` for "subdirectories too" for instance (see

```
xcopy /?
```

directly from the prompt for more options...)